# criação de tabelas com margem entre elas

Tags: html, table

Quero criar uma especia de tabela mas com espaçamento entre cada retangulo.

O que tenho criado é:

```
<table border="1" margin="2">
 <tr>
   <td>Célula 1</td>
   <td>Célula 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Célula 3</td>
   <td>Célula 4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

e o que quero é algo assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize o atributto `border-collapse: separate` e no `border-spacing` você define a distância entre as células.

```css
table {border: 0px; border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate;}
table td{border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; padding: 5px; margin: 5px}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

O que tens de fazer é definir a borda para cada `td`, algo como:

```
<style>
    td {
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
```

Remove também o `border = "1"` que definis-te na tabela.

```css
td {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table margin="2">
 <tr>
   <td>Célula 1</td>
   <td>Célula 2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Célula 3</td>
   <td>Célula 4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Tens [AQUI](http://jsfiddle.net/o8mfmjf4/1/) um exemplo.